# Caesar Cipher validation

Tags: python

I'm making a Caesar cipher and everything is exactly how I wanted it but when it comes to validation if I enter '123' it outputs 'Your translated text is:  123'
when I want it to return back to getMessage() and tell the user that the input was invalid. Help would be greatly appreciated because I have been struggling with this for days.

Thanks in advance.

```
            def getMode():
                 while True:
                     mode = input('Do you wish to encrypt(e) or decrypt(d) a message: ').lower()
                     if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
                         return mode
                     else:
                         print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

            def getMessage():
                 message = input('Enter your message: ')
                 return message

            def getKey():
                 key = 0
                 while True:
                     key = 5
                     return key

            def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
                 if mode[0] == 'd':
                     key = -key
                 translated = ''

                 for symbol in message:
                     if symbol.isalpha():
                         num = ord(symbol)
                         num += key

                         if symbol.isupper():
                             if num > ord('Z'):
                                 num -= 26
                             elif num < ord('A'):
                                 num += 26
                         elif symbol.islower():
                             if num > ord('z'):
                                 num -= 26
                             elif num < ord('a'):
                                 num += 26

                         translated += chr(num)
                     else:
                         translated += symbol
                 return translated



            mode = getMode()
            message = getMessage()
            key = getKey()

            print('Your translated text is: ', getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: Lots of options here. Off the top of my head: 1. set a global flag if you *did* convert a character; 2. set a flag if you did *not* convert a character; 3. compare input to output. What to do depends on what you think should issue an error - is `ab12` -> `xy12` an error or not? What about spaces and punctuation?

Comment: @Jongware yes that should be an error I dont want to mix alpha characters and numbers.

Comment: Well your last lines `else translated += symbol`  makes it accept any invalid input, so that's the point to interfere then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to allow alpha characters:

```
def getMessage():
    while True:
        message = input('Enter your message: ')
        if message.isalpha():
            return message
        print("Invalid input, text must contain alphabetic characters only.")
```

To allow spaces and letters:

```
 if all(ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace() for ch in message):
            return message
```

A dict and using modulo is going to be a much more concise approach:

```
def get_mode():
    while True:
        mode = input('Do you wish to encrypt(e) or decrypt(d) a message: ').lower()
        if mode.lower() in {"e","d"}:
            return mode
        print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

def get_message():
    while True:
        message = input('Enter your message: ')
        if all(ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace() for ch in message):
            return message
        print("Invalid input, text must contain alphabetic characters only.")

def get_key():
    return 5

from string import ascii_letters

d = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(ascii_letters)}

enc = ascii_letters

def get_translated_message(mode, message, key):
    if mode == "e":
        return "".join([enc[(d[ch] + key) % 52] if not ch.isspace() else ch for ch in message])
    return "".join([enc[(d[ch] - key) % 52] if not ch.isspace() else ch for ch in message])
```

Just run  it the same way:

```
mode = get_mode()
message = get_message()
key = get_key()

print('Your translated text is: ', get_translated_message(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: yeah theres just one thing I need to be able to use whitespaces in my inputs and it should output with a space too.

Comment: So just whitespace and letters yes?

Comment: Where would I put the if statement?

Comment: instead of if message.isalpha():, a dictionary would make your translating a whole lot simpler

Comment: Hmm if I enter anything I get back: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isalpsha' on line 13

Comment: @NodeMN, that would be a typo, fixed

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly so far but how do I replace a '%' with a whitespace when I input a message with a space. And when decrypting it appears as a empty square.

Comment: you want to replace  a space with "%"?

Comment: @NodeMN You have added two new requirements so far in the comments. It really would have been more helpful if you were explicit about these things in your original post to specify what exactly is giving you difficulties in your implementation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no I mean if I enter 'abc abc' it outputs as 'fgh%fgh' when I would like it to output as 'fgh fgh' same goes with decrypt. When I input 'abc abc' to decrypt it ouputs as 'vwx(empytybox)vwx'

Comment: @idjaw Sorry I will keep that in mind when I ask a new question

Comment: I will add a version using a dict which will make life a lot simpler

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you but I cant put in mode = getMode(), message and key as well as the final print. Is there an easier way to do this or is it just a format problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry ive asked for alot but could you put in your code with the bottom part of mine to make it work. It would be a real big help.

Comment: @NodeMN, it is exactly the same way as your own, I added the code at the bottom

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you so so much. This works exactly how I wanted

Comment: No worries, there are a lot of different ways to go about it but dicts are definitely worth getting familiar with

Comment: @PadraicCunningham using the line 'if all(ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace() for ch in message):' how can I make it so the input must be answered (not left blank) and with at least 1 alphabetic character so the user doesn't just input spaces and gets a result print of nothing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you want to return an error if the user enters something like '123'. Based off of that requirement, the problem in your code is right here:

You are doing this check:

```
if symbol.isalpha():
```

Which will check if something is of alpha: `A-Z`

Therefore, in your else, you want to return your error when the alpha check fails:

So when you do this:

```
else:
    translated += symbol
```

You want this:

```
else:
    return "input invalid"
```

However, again, focusing on your code, this brings up another problem. You need to change how you are handling the return of your method, so the output makes more sense. You might want to consider something like this:

```
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()

result = getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key)
if not result:
    print("invalid")
else:
    print('Your translated text is: ', result)
```

Based on recent updates, you are looking to preserve whitespace. Therefore, you should consider changing your code to also handle whitespace by simply adding an `elif` condition for checking for whitespace and adding `' '` to your `translated` variable. So, the code in your for loop would then look like this:

```
 for symbol in message:
         if symbol.isalpha():
             num = ord(symbol)
             num += key

             if symbol.isupper():
                 if num > ord('Z'):
                     num -= 26
                 elif num < ord('A'):
                     num += 26
             elif symbol.islower():
                 if num > ord('z'):
                     num -= 26
                 elif num < ord('a'):
                     num += 26

             translated += chr(num)
         elif symbol.isspace():
             translated += ' '
         else:
            return False
```

But Padraic's approach is really good and is definitely worth a look to consider refactoring.

Comment: I've looked through the code and cant find a way to only ask for: message = getMessage() and not: mode = getMode(). Basically if you input an invalid message I want to asks for the message again rather than asking if you want to encrypt or decrypt. @idjaw

Comment: After thoroughly looking through the code I still cant find what causes this. Is it something to do with the while True loop at the bottom or what.