# how do i shift the list by the amount of spaces of the key

Tags: python, encryption

```
alpha_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
alpha_list_2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]



def get_mode():
    while True:
        mode = input("Would you like to 'encrypt' or 'decrypt' a message?").lower()
        if mode == "encrypt" or mode == "decrypt":
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter "encrypt" or "decrypt"')


def get_message():
    message_2 = input("Enter your message:")
    return message_2

def get_key():
    key = ""

    key = input("Enter a key with no two letters being the same:").strip().lower()

    for letter in alpha_list:
        if letter in key:
            alpha_list.remove(letter)

    for letter in key[::-1]:
        alpha_list.insert(0, letter)

def get_translated_message(mode, message, key):
    if mode == "decrypt":
        key = -key
    translated = " "
    for letter in alpha_list_2:
        num = alpha_list_2.index(letter)

        num += shift



mode = get_mode()
message = get_message()
key = get_key()
shift = len(key)
print("Your translated message is:")
print(get_translated_message(mode, message, key))
```

This code is my attempt to create a keyword cipher. The problem I am having is when I try to encrypt the message using:

```
num += shift
```

I get a `TypeError`

The keyword cipher works by asking the user for a key then inserting it at the beginning of the alphabet, all letters in the key that were in the alphabet will be removed and the index of all the letters will be changed.

Comment: You are not returning anything from get_key so `shift = len(key)` is trying to get the length of None, your encrypt and decrypt logic is also not going to work,something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720187/caesar-cipher-validation/33720288#33720288 woud be much simpler

Comment: shift has no value on the get_translated_message, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong in your code.
First is that `get_key` is not returning anything, so `shift = len(key)` gives shift a value of `None`

Second is that on the function `get_translated_message` when you do `num += shift` the shift variable here has no value, since it was declared outside the scope of the function. Pass the shift as parameter.